# Ignoring a specific folder in target from being cleaned in maven

Tags: maven, maven-plugin

I have situation where i am running 2 maven commands back to back to run 2 different set of tests.

However i need the final target folder to have results of both maven commands. Problem is that the second maven command cleans the target folder. Is it possible to ask mvn to not clean a specific folder in target.

Comment: You can use Maven profiles to configure the clean plugin differently. Pay attention to the `excludeDefaultDirectories` option (https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-clean-plugin/clean-mojo.html#excludeDefaultDirectories) that has to be set if you want the plugin not to clean the default directories it clean.

Comment: Why are you running 2 Maven commands to begin with? You can do it in one. What are the commands?

Comment: I would suggest to hardly think about your tests. They are not unit tests they are integration tests. I would change them...instead of working around your problem with Maven..The root cause of your problem are those tests..